# Android - Set Clicked focus on Button

Tags: android, button

I am having 4 buttons in my layout, now whenever i click any button, after the click event, button should be highlighed showing that it was clicked last.

For making such thing, i have tried the following:

code:

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new button_click_listener());
btn2.setOnClickListener(new button_click_listener());


class button_click_listener implements Button.OnClickListener
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
       if(v==btn1)
       {
            btn1.requestFocus();
       }

       if(v==btn2)
       {
            btn2.requestFocus();
       }
        .......
    }
}
```

XML Layout:

```
<Button 
   android:text="Click 1" 
   android:id="@+id/btnClick1" 
   android:layout_width="70dp" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
   android:padding="10dp"
   android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
</Button>
```

**How do i show clicked highlight on the button that was clicked last?
Please, show me a way and give suggestions.**

### Update:

If i set **`android:focusable="true"`** then button is highlighted and focused, but then at the same time, i need to click twice on the button to perform the actual click event.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm having a similar issue

Answer (score 3):

its easy buddy...just you have to set backgroundcolor of ur button on ur click event and each time any button clicked u have to set other buttons background color null

Answer (score 0):

This functionality resembles RadioButtonGroup, customize RadioButtonGroup to your requirements.

Setting Style in RadioGroup by :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_window_focused="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/radio_hover" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_window_focused="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/radio_normal" />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/radio_active" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/radio_active" />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/radio_hover" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/radio_normal_off" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/radio_normal" />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/radio_hover" />
    </selector>
```

Set this Selector to your Radio button.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you need a new state. Follow the directions here and add a "state_highlighted", or whatever you'd like to call it:

[How to add a custom button state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336060/android-how-to-add-a-custom-button-state)