# How to set focus on button if clicked and buttons are made in xml

Tags: android

I have created 3 buttons and i want to change focus of that button which is clicked by user
using coding is there any way ?

i have seen these links

**[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9750097/how-can-a-button-get-the-focus)**

**[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680065/android-set-clicked-focus-on-button)**

but what i want to know that when i made instances of these 3 buttons i only want focus which is clicked at that time and i want to change focuscolor on click defined by me using coding?
Can anybody tell me?

Answer (score 0):

```
   final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
     button.setFocusable(true);
      button.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Try this sample code