# Android: Highlight the Image Selected in Gallery

Tags: android

i want to highlight the currently selected image in gallery. 
is der any way to have that?

Thanks,
Nital

Comment: This [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5806001/10119) is a good write-up, with explanation, and credit to the original author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [StateListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html)

EDIT:

You can use the mergeDrawableStates() method of the View class to provide your custom states:

[http://code.google.com/android/reference/android/view/View.html#mergeDrawableStates(int[],%20int[])](http://code.google.com/android/reference/android/view/View.html#mergeDrawableStates%28int%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D%29)

Try the steps below to create new custom states:

1) Define the state resources in res/values/attrs.xml

```
<declare-styleable name="MyCustomState">
        <attr name="state_fried" format="boolean" />
        <attr name="state_baked" format="boolean" />
    </declare-styleable>
```

2) In your custom view class :

A)   Declare the state variables:

```
private static final int[] FRIED_STATE_SET = {
        R.attr.state_fried
   };

   private static final int[] BAKED_STATE_SET = {
        R.attr.state_baked
   };
```

B) Override the onCreateDrawableState() method:

```
 @Override
    protected int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace) {
        final int[] drawableState = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 2);
        if (isFried()) {
            mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, FRIED_STATE_SET);
        }
        if (isBaked()) {
            mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, BAKED_STATE_SET);
        }
        return drawableState;
    }
```

Once this is done, you should be able to use these in ColorStateListDrawable, but you should use your app's namespace to use these new states:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/<my_app_package>">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/item_baked" state_baked="true"
state_fried="false" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/item_fried" state_baked="false"
state_fried="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/item_overcooked" state_baked="true"
state_fried="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/item_raw" state_baked="false"
state_fried="false" />
</selector>
```

Comment: i have done something like this: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item 
 android:state_selected="false"
    android:state_pressed="false" 
    android:drawable="@color/black" />
<item android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@color/white" />
<item android:state_selected="true"
     android:drawable="@color/white"
      />
</selector>
'

Comment: Wow.  It appears, that unless @evilone posted the answer 3 years ago under another name s/he copied it verbatim from this google groups post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/uqr2BNI7NZo

Comment: @Chasler Wow, you're a genius. I think this is not illegal.