# What is the AmazonApp store alternative for market:// URL to open an app page (for rating purposes)

Tags: android, kindle-fire, amazon-appstore

In my android app I do give users an option to rate my app (a 'rate me' button within the app menu). For GooglePlay version I use the **market://** URL scheme to open the GooglePlay app. For an app build that reaches Amazon I do open an http:// url that shows my app on Amazon Store ... but I do wonder if there is a better way. A way to open Amazon AppStore directly using an Intent.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is amazon appstore app present in your mobile?? If yes then just pass the package name in the intent.putextra part

Answer (score 0):

Ahhhh... as often, I finally managed to google the answer gew minutes after rasing a question:

https://developer.amazon.com/public/community/post/Tx3A1TVL67TB24B/Linking-To-the-Amazon-Appstore-for-Android

Trying it right now.

Works like charm, though crashes if AppStore is not available on device. I will put it in a Try/Catch and use the second link format if first attempt fails.

Comment: check this answer to see how to detect if your app was installed from Amazon AppStore - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19592927/is-it-possible-to-reliably-detect-at-runtime-which-store-installed-an-android-ap/19643816#19643816