# Android SDK, Check if device is Amazon-FireTV

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-fire-tv

I am trying to write a simple piece of code that will execute some other code if true. What I want to do is check if my app is running on the 'Amazon Fire-TV (BOX, not the Fire-TV stick)' I think it would not be that hard to do but I am guessing it would be something like this?

```
String osName = android.getSystemOS();    

if(!osName.equals("AMAZON FIRE-TV")){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.class, "This app may not be compatible with your device..., Toast.LENGTH_LONG").show();
   ...

}
```

Comment: see answer below, curious what you're developing that will run on FireTV, but not on Stick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check any device name specifically using:

```
boolean isFireTV = Build.MODEL.equalsIgnoreCase("AFTB");
```

(see [this page](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/devices/fire-tv/docs/device-and-platform-specifications) for FireTV model strings, and [this one](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/devices/fire-tablets/specifications/01-device-and-feature-specifications) for Fire Tablets)

I'd also [check out this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19592927/is-it-possible-to-reliably-detect-at-runtime-which-store-installed-an-android-ap/19643816#19643816) for a more generic test to help you determine if your app is running on an Amazond device, or installed via the Amazon AppStore (eg on a Blackberry device)

Answer (score 2):

the following function:

```
public static boolean isTV() {
    return android.os.Build.MODEL.contains("AFT");
}
```

should detect either firetv or fire tv stick

see

https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/devices/fire-tv/docs/amazon-fire-tv-sdk-frequently-asked-questions

for details