# Push Notifications: how to implement an Android App using GCM and ADM?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

At the moment I have an android app on the Play Store and on the Amazon Store.

I need to implement push notifications and I need to use Amazon Simple Notification Service.

I've already implemented the Android part and it's all ok, but when I run the app on an amazon device push notification system doesn't work. I've discovered that GCM is not supported by Amazon devices. (nice..)

**So, I guess that what I need to do is that my android app utilizes GCM if running on an Android Device and ADM if running on an amazon device.**

Is it possible to do that with a single application? Is there anybody who did this in the past? I can't find a lot on the internet regarding this topic

Thank you very much for helping me

Answer (score 0):

Yes using GCM on Android and ADM on Amazon devices is the correct way to go. For using ADM with SNS, this guide will probably help http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-adm.html

As far as using a single application, it looks like others have asked this and it's not the *best* approach but it seems like it can work.  Checkout

[Is it possible to reliably detect at runtime which store installed an Android App (Google Play or Amazon Market)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19592927/is-it-possible-to-reliably-detect-at-runtime-which-store-installed-an-android-ap/19643816#19643816)

[Detect app is running on Kindle Fire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309624/detect-app-is-running-on-kindle-fire)

Hope this helps