# Can't set same package and app name for demo and full app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, package, google-play

I want to set the package name for **demo app** like *com.example.myapp*
and want to set the package name for **full app** like *com.example.myapp* I want to set package name same because their same app but one has full futures.

We have *a full app* that includes all futures and I also have *a demo app* for limited futures. Now I want to publish these to apps on Play Store. What should I configure before handing in?

*I find [About demo and full app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39505331/managing-demo-full-version-of-my-app-in-codename-one) but it is more than 3 years ago , and it was eclipse. We are using Android Studio*

Question 1: **Should I change the package name?**

Additionally **I want to mention that I don't want to publish one app and put it Extra futures for paid. I want to publish  two apps, that one is demo of  full app, and another one is full app**, such as *Vector game on play store*

**If the answer is changing the package name for making demo app of full app, please let us know**
We are two friends that working on a project we made, we are waiting your answers

**Thank you ALL**

Comment: Aren't you using flavors for separating demo and full builds? If so, you can have a different`applicationIdSuffix` which will allow you to publish both apps under different packages without changing your code.

Comment: Demo app is 1200 line of codes, and Full app is 2300 line of codes. and has a too many futures. But should't know what to do

Comment: too many people said me that I should publish , with the same package name , because of it is same app, but something i should do different

Comment: Just use separate package names. Package names don't mean anything in the end, just remember that you can't change them ever without republishing.

Comment: can you please note what is applicationIdsuffix? saying that did you mean that same package name but appname diifferent?

Answer (score 0):

You can't publish 2 apps with same package name. With productFlavors, you can set different package names for different flavors from same code base.

Comment: they was expalined same package name but demo app has additional words in package name but it was eclipse and before 3 years, may be you can explain to me what to do  with that  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39505331/managing-demo-full-version-of-my-app-in-codename-one

Comment: Just 1 additional letter can make package different from another. Play Store would consider these as 2 different apps: com.my.app1, com.my.app2

Comment: Thank you but what happens if: com.my.app and com.mydemo.app

Comment: Those 2 will be published and shown as 2 totally different apps on Google Store. You can provide link in App descriptions to link them. For example in Demo app, you provide a link for users to download full app.