# Android library project with no Activities but with resources. Best approach?

Tags: android, android-resources, applicationcontext, library-project

So currently i have a library project that contains no Activities whatsoever, but it does have resource files, like layouts for compound views and strings that are accessible from dialogFraments and normal classes. Currently this library project extends Application, and the main app extends from the library project application. Is this the right approach?

Application <-LIBRARY PROJECT:BaseApplicationContext <- MAIN PROJECT - ApplicationContext

regards,

Comment: If it works for you then it's the right approach, otherwise it's a wrong approach.

Comment: I'm doing this on a current project with only minor issues; have a look at this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087744/how-to-solve-android-libraries-custom-attributes-and-package-name-remapping-duri

Comment: Thanks, let me check.

Comment: So you're also extending the application from one of the main libraries? Sorry for late response.