# Android: custom selector state never gets "true"

Tags: android, android-selector, android-custom-attributes

I'm struggling with this already from hours and I cannot find a solution, I hope someone can help me.
I have a ListView with a custom adapter extending BaseAdapter and each element of the list extends a LinearLayout containing only a TextView. I started basically from [How to add a custom button state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336060/android-how-to-add-a-custom-button-state).
This is the list_item.xml layout file of the list element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.mypackage"
    android:id="@+id/newItem"
    app:state_playing="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/item_selector"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        style="@style/Text_View_Style_White"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@drawable/item_text_selector" /> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the relevant code of the BaseAdapter:

```
  class AlbumListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Checkable {

    private Context mContext;

    public AlbumListAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return listSize; // is a variable
     }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        AlbumViewHolder albumHolder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            // Inflate the layout
            LayoutInflater li = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            albumHolder = new AlbumViewHolder(mContext, null);
            albumHolder.albumTitle = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.textview);

            convertView.setTag(albumHolder);
        } else {
            albumHolder = (AlbumViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        albumHolder.albumTitle.setText("Some text in the TextView");
        albumHolder.albumTitle.setSelected(true);

        if (myBooleanCondition) 
        {
            albumHolder.setPlaying(true);
            albumHolder.refreshDrawableState();

            for (int i = 0; i < albumHolder.getDrawableState().length; i++) {
                if (albumHolder.getDrawableState()[i] != 0)
                    System.out.println(TAG + " State i = "
                    + i + " -> " + getResources().getResourceEntryName(albumHolder.getDrawableState()[i]));
            }
        }

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

and here the list element class extending the LinearLayout:

```
static class AlbumViewHolder extends LinearLayout {

        private static final int[] STATE_PLAYING_SET = { R.attr.state_playing };
        private boolean mIsPlaying = false;
        TextView albumTitle;

        public AlbumViewHolder(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }

        public void setPlaying(boolean isPlaying) {
            mIsPlaying = isPlaying;
        }

        @Override
        protected int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace) {
            final int[] drawableState = super
                    .onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 1);
            if (mIsPlaying) {
                System.out.println(TAG
                        + " - onCreateDrawableState() -> mIsPlaying = "
                        + mIsPlaying);
                mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, STATE_PLAYING_SET);
            }
            return drawableState;
        }
    }
```

Here is the attrs.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="music">
        <attr name="state_playing" format="boolean" />
        <attr name="playing" format="boolean" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

and here the 2 selectors trying to use the selector state `state_playing`, one for the background of the LinearLayout of each element (item_selector.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.mypackage">

    <item android:drawable="@color/blue_fluo3" app:state_playing="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/orange_fluo" android:state_pressed="true" app:state_playing="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/orange_fluo" android:state_activated="true" app:state_playing="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" app:state_playing="false"/>

</selector>
```

and one for the textColor of the TextView (item_text_selector.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.mypackage">

    <item app:state_playing="true" android:color="@color/orange_fluo"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" app:state_playing="false" android:color="@color/black"/>
    <item android:state_activated="true" app:state_playing="false" android:color="@color/black"/>
    <item app:state_playing="false" android:color="@android:color/white"/>

</selector>
```

The result is the same for both: the state_playing seems to work but only in state "false", because if I add a line at the beginning of the selector state list with `<item app:state_playing="false" android:color="@color/yellow"/>` for the text selector and `<item android:drawable="@color/red" app:state_playing="false"/>` for the background selector everything is working as expected, I can see the LinearLayout with red background and the text with yellow text!
I really don't know what to try anymore... (even if I set the property by default to the objects (`app:state_playing="true"`) in the xml layout it doesn't work!

Any help, hint or experience sharing is extremely appreciated!

Comment: no idea about this?! If needed I can provide more info!

Answer (score 0):

It looks okay to me,but I'd suggest setting duplicateParentState in the container layout as below. I have a vague memory of having issues along those lines myself...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.mypackage"
android:id="@+id/newItem"
android:duplicateParentState="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/item_selector"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    style="@style/Text_View_Style_White"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:duplicateParentState="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="@drawable/item_text_selector" />
```