# Android: Selector on custom View Attribute

Tags: android, layout

I have tried to folow this guide: [How to add a custom button state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336060/android-how-to-add-a-custom-button-state), to create my own view attribute, and using an selector to change its state.
I can't seem to get it to work. The selector for button works fine on non-custom selectors, such as button pressed, but doesn't work for my costum selector.
My code is as follows:

in attrs.xml:

```xml
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="ValueButton">
        <attr name="toggle" format="boolean" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

In my custom button class definition file, called ValueButton.java:

```java
public class ValueButton extends Button
{
    private static final int[] STATE_TOGLLE = {R.attr.toggle};
    private boolean toggle = false;

    public void setToggle(boolean val)
    {
        toggle = val;
    }

    public ValueButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        }

    @Override
    protected int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace) {
        final int[] drawableState = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 2);
        if(toggle)
            mergeDrawableStates(drawableState,STATE_TOGLLE);
        return drawableState;
    }
}
```

In my view that uses the button:

```xml
<LiniarLayout>
    <com.myapp.ValueButton
            android:id="@+id/rightText"
            custom:toggle="false"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            style="@style/ValueSwitchStyle"
     />
</LiniarLayout>
```

in my styles.xml file:

```xml
<style name="ValueSwitchStyle">
     <item name="android:background">@drawable/value_switch_background</item>
</style>
```

and finally my background definitions file (button_background.xml), located in the drawables folder:

```xml
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/com.myapp.ValueButton">
    <item custom:toggle="true" android:drawable="@color/blue"/>
    <item custom:toggle="false" android:drawable="@color/white"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: What does the line         final int[] drawableState = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 2);
 do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you missed the `refreshDrawableState` call

```
public void setToggle(boolean val) {
        toggle = val;
        refreshDrawableState();
}
```

from the documentation

> Call this to force a view to update its drawable state.

Comment: setToggle is never called in my app, its only there for future code.
Your solution doesn't work.

Comment: You have to read the custom state from the attrs object you get in the constructor, set the boolean and call refreshDrawableState