# Android: Cannot Resolve Method

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to program custom states for programatically generated buttons in my app using the process explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336060/android-how-to-add-a-custom-button-state), but i'm getting the "cannot resolve method" compiler error when I try to call a method in my custom button class. The method i'm trying to call is public so I'm not sure why it's not visible in the scope i'm trying to call it from. Thoughts?

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_fragment, container, false);
    typeOneArray = new boolean[21];          
    typeTwoArray = new int[21];      
    //programmatic button generation
    buttonHolder = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonLayoutParent);  
    buttonHolder.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);                                 
    for (int j = 0; j < 21; j++) {
        final int iteration = j;
        final Button btnTag = new CustomButton(getActivity());                      //CUSTOM BUTTON INSTANTIATION
        btnTag.setId(j);                                  
        btnTag.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_button);
        buttonHolder.addView(btnTag);
        btnTag.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {     //button was clicked
                    //clickCounter0++;
                    typeTwoArray[iteration] = typeTwoArray[iteration] + 1;
                    Handler handler = new Handler();
                    Runnable singleClickLogic = new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if (typeTwoArray[iteration] !=0) {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "single click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                typeTwoArray[iteration] = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    //Double click
                    if (typeTwoArray[iteration] == 2) {
                        btnTag.setButtonTypeOne(true);              //THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR HAPPENS

                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "double click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        typeTwoArray[iteration] = 0;
                    }
                    //Single click
                    else if (typeTwoArray[iteration] == 1) {
                        handler.postDelayed(singleClickLogic, 250);                 
                    }
                } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {                

                }
                return  false;
            }
        });
    }
    return v;
}
```

**CustomButton.java**

```
public class CustomButton extends Button {
private boolean stateTwo = false;
private boolean stateOne = false;
private static final int[] STATE_ONE = {R.attr.state_one};
private static final int[] STATE_TWO = {R.attr.state_two};

public CustomButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public void setButtonTypeOne(boolean buttonState) {
    stateOne = buttonState;
}
public void setButtonTypeTwo(boolean buttonState) {
    stateTwo = buttonState;
}

@Override
protected int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace) {
    final int[] drawableState = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 2);
    if (stateOne) {
        mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, STATE_ONE);
    }
    if (stateTwo) {
        mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, STATE_TWO);
    }
    return drawableState;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though the `btnTag` instance is a `CustomButton`, you've declared `btnTag` as just a regular `Button`.

```
final Button btnTag = new CustomButton(getActivity());
```

`Button` doesn't have your custom methods, so the compiler can't find `setButtonTypeOne()`.

You can either declare `btnTag` as your `CustomButton` type:

```
final CustomButton btnTag = ...
```

Or cast it to that type before calling the method on it:

```
((CustomButton) btnTag).setButtonTypeOne(true);
```