# Setting error state in EditText through styles

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an Edittext with below style

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/white" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/yellow" android:state_focused="false" />
    <item android:color="@color/white" android:state_active="true" />
</selector>
```

And in the Edittext style I apply

```
<item name="backgroundTint">@drawable/states_edit_text</item>
```

and it works. This changes the EditTexts bottom line color in states normal and focused . I need to change the tint color to red when its in the error state.

Something like

```
<item android:state_error="true" android:color="@color/red"></item>
```

But there is no state called error, I referred to other answers and they recommend to achieve it through code. is there any way using android styles, I can set the EditText tint to red on error state?

Comment: You could make a custom EditText with your own states. [Here is an detail example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336060/how-to-add-a-custom-button-state)

Comment: Why don't you use TextInputLayout and EditText which has error state and color itself?

Comment: @EhsanMashhadi I knew the solution with TextinputLayout, but this was an already existing code where a lot of EditTexts are there in several screens. We need to make this change in every EditText. Since all these EditTexts have the same style, I was trying some solution with the styles only.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can change it programmatically :

```
if (!trueState){

ColorStateList colorStateList = ColorStateList.valueOf(color)
editText.setSupportBackgroundTintList(colorStateList)

}
```

This will give the EditText the desired underline color.