# How can I change the EditText style programatically in Android?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-styles

Hi I have a view with a form, and all button, labels, EditText, etc, are defined in a styles files, for example, for **EditText** I have ***app_edit_text*** and ***app_edit_text_error***, my question is how can change in **EditText** the style from ***app_edit_text*** to ***app_edit_text_error***?.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest you can't change style programaticaly. You can only change text 
 appearance using `setTextAppearance(int resId)` method:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setTextAppearance(int)

For your purpose you can use `setError(String error)` method of EditText or implement self states and handle it in EditText subclass. Here is good post about custom states: [How to add a custom button state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336060/how-to-add-a-custom-button-state)

Answer (score 0):

You can't change styles programatically. You can either replace them with a new Instance (you can specify the styles in the constructor only) or you can use it with a new theme since theme can be changed programatically. 
[Themes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes#fromTheApp)