# Can we add Visual States for a normal view(eg., Label) with Tap Gesture Recognizer?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Due to some complicated UI requirements, we are using Frame with Tap Gesture as a replacement of Button. Is it possible to add Visual States("Focused", "Clicked", "Disabled") for a normal view?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a custom button state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336060/how-to-add-a-custom-button-state)

Comment: Hi , I think Frame is well for this , could you share more info not using Frame to implement it .

Comment: I need to add custom states for a view(frame), not button, in Xamarin forms. Any suggestions for it?

Comment: @ChrisTina You can use [Bindable Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties#create-a-property) to create custom property for Frame .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom `Frame` to add custom [bindable properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties#create-a-property) to implement it .For example , add three properties for `CustomFrame` . You can add other more custom property by what needed.

```
public class CustomFrame :Frame
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty CustomFocusedProperty = BindableProperty.Create("CustomFocused", typeof(bool), typeof(CustomFrame), null);

    public bool CustomFocused
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(CustomFocusedProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CustomFocusedProperty, value); }
    }


    public static readonly BindableProperty CustomClickedProperty = BindableProperty.Create("CustomClicked", typeof(bool), typeof(CustomFrame), null);

    public bool CustomClicked
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(CustomClickedProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CustomClickedProperty, value); }
    }


    public static readonly BindableProperty CustomDisabledProperty = BindableProperty.Create("DisabledFocused", typeof(bool), typeof(CustomFrame), null);

    public bool DisabledFocused
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(CustomDisabledProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CustomDisabledProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Uesd in **Xaml** : `<local:CustomFrame x:Name="CustomFrame" />`

Then you can set or get vaule from custom property :

```
CustomFrame.CustomClicked = true;
CustomFrame.CustomFocused = true;
CustomFrame.CustomDisabled = true;
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try doing this.

Comment: @ChrisTina OK , if answer be helpful , remember to back and mark it :)